# Which unary or binary logical operators existed in logic before 1854 besides 'and', 'or', and 'not'?

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy, history-of-logic

Logical operators are a central focus of logicians, and two important books with innovative thoughts on logic include *Begriffsschrift* (1879) by [Gottlob Frege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottlob_Frege) and [*The Laws of Thought*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laws_of_Thought) by [George Boole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole) in 1854. The contribution of Boolean Algebra is memorable for the formalization of an algebra with the [logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) AND, OR, and NOT. **Before 1854, were there other logical operators, and if such an operator(s) existed what was the motivation for their creation?**

Comment: Why 1878? And existed how, with a special symbol? If-then, not-and, not-or, exclusive or, are commonplace in natural language. Material implication goes back to [Philo the Dialectician (c. 300 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo_the_Dialectician#Philosophy), Leibniz had symbols for it, its reverse and the biconditional, Venn had a symbol for symmetric difference, a.k.a. exclusive or, see [Origins of Boolean Algebra in the Logic of Classes](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/46/Pengelley_projects/Project-7/Project-7-boole-venn-peirce.pdf).

Comment: You'll love [Lambert's list (1782)](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/math-origins-the-logical-ideas), although the language of "logical operators" is so anachronistic I am not sure there were any even in 1878.

Comment: You may have a look at the logic of the Stoics.

Comment: See : Wolfgang Lenzen, [Leibniz’s Logic and the Cube of Opposition (Log Uni, 2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11787-016-0143-2) for some example regarding Leibniz.